# libvlc - how to set the audio channel

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I can play the video.
However I can't set the audio channel to 3. (Set to left outout only)

(libvlc_audio_set_channel) It always return -1.

```
[DllImport("libvlc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern int libvlc_audio_set_channel(IntPtr libvlc_media_player, int channel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason.

Need to ensure the video is playing , and wait some time , maybe delay 1 second to apply the change

Comment: I would be interested to know if you try it with the latest vlc-git whether this delay is still needed. I made a possibly related fix to do with setting volume.

Comment: I am using latest libvlc. To fix the problem. I create a new thread. While it is return -1 then sleep 1 second and do it again until it returns 0

Comment: I understand your workaround, but did you build libvlc yourself from the latest (as of yesterday) vlc-git and try that? It might be fixed and your workaround might not be needed anymore.